# Minecraft Fabric Moding: how to increase tick rate for only one class?

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

I am relatively new to programming Minecraft Mods and just tried to code a client side mode using the fabirc API.

My problem so far is, that I want to animate my currently held Item, so I coded a way to move and rotate the Item.
But now I can clearly see that the movement is relatively clunky, even though I am using a de Casteljau Algorithm to compute the new position of my Item

So my question is:

Is there A way to execute my code at a higher rate, as once per tick (20 times a second)?
Something like once half a tick (40 times a second) or even more

[image: Current Process]

[if the above gif isnt loading](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/706821180426027058/1043192751971377234/ezgif.com-gif-maker.gif)